# The exponent delta of the variance recursion in a GARCH model

Tags: variance, garch, volatility-forecasting

The function `garchFit` in R for GARCH modeling, among the various possibilities include a parameter "delta" described as the exponent of variance recursion. I've read the paper of Ding, Granger and Engle (1993) on APARCH models and this parameter is used in the specification of variance. I cannot find any theoretical paper or book that discusses the issue for classical GARCH models and in particular I need the equation that includes this parameter (I think it can be easily derived from that paper).

Can you help me to understand its use and how it changes the specification of traditional GARCH (Bollerslev)?

Answer (score 1):

The APARCH model is defined as (see [vlab](https://vlab.stern.nyu.edu/doc/5?topic=mdls))

\begin{equation}
\sigma_t^\delta  = \omega + \sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i (\vert \epsilon_{t-i} \vert - \gamma_i \epsilon_{t-i})^\delta + \sum_{j=1}^q \beta_j \sigma_{t-j}^\delta
\end{equation}

Thus, the GARCH model is obtained by setting $\delta = 2$ and $\gamma_i = 0$ for all $i=1,...,p$. The model is specified in general terms, where the GARCH model simply is a special case.